# Entity Framework Attach error: An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, dbcontext

I'm a newbie with Entity Framework, and I have looked at the questions with the same title, but I haven't found a satisfying answer yet.

Here is my class:

```
public class MyUser
{
 public string FirstName { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<ProfileSkillEdu> Skills { get; set; }
}
```

And in the controller I have:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditProfile(MyUser user, string emailAddress)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _unitOfWork.GetMyUserRepository().Update(user);
                _unitOfWork.Save();
                return View(user);
            }
        }
        catch (DataException)
        {
            //Log the error 
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

In my user repository:

```
public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
    {
        dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);

        context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;

    }
```

I keep getting **An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.** at  dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate). I watched the variables and I found that if MyUser has only 1 Skill object, it's fine because when it does Attach, the key is unique (value is 0). But if MyUser has 2 skill objects, both primary key have the value of 0 and therefore the error.

Can someone explain why all the Skill object's primary key have the values of 0? Also, is there a simple solution to this problem? I thought it's supposed to be straight forward but I have been struggling with this for hours.

Edit:

I wonder if the problem is because of how I use the context.

In the controller definition I have:

```
public class MyAccountController : Controller
{
IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

 public ActionResult EditProfile()
    {
        if (_user == null)
        {
            MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();

            if (currentUser == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Logon", "Account");
            }
            Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

            MyUserService svc = new MyUserService();

            MyUser user = svc.GetUserLoaded(currentUserId); //this uses include/eager loading to get the Skills too.

            if (user == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Logon", "Account");
            }
            else
                _user = user;
        }

        return View(_user);
    }
}
```

In my UnitOfWork I have:

```
public class UnitOfWork:IUnitOfWork
{
    private GlobalContext context = new GlobalContext();

    private GenericRepository<MyUser> myUserRepository;
    private GenericRepository<Skill> skillRepository;

    .. and implementation of Save() and Dispose()
}
```

Comment: explain how u are using your context across ur application. and also is the relationship between MyUser and ProfileSkillEdu well defined?

Comment: Most probably PK values of `Skill` objects are not posted back.

Comment: Tsegay, MyUser has an IUnitofWork field, and inside the unit of work there are repositories for each object (so UserRepository, SkillRepository, etc). The repository has the context object in it.

Comment: FYI, my context is disposed after every request. So EditPRofile and EditProfile POST uses different context. Is this why the Id is 0 for the navigation property objects?

Comment: Are you certain the context is disposed after every request? Have you set a breakpoint to ensure that? I've seen cases where dependency injection is used and a bug exists that the dispose was never called on the UoW or repository and thus context didn't get disposed.

Comment: Yes I debugged it and it was called after EditProfile() so I assume that it's a new context that is used at httpPost EditProfile(). I also found that the way I call GetUserLoaded() returns a detached object, not Unchanged. Will that be a problem?